# iOS 8 vibrancy image not showing on device

Tags: ios, iphone, uivisualeffectview

So I created a simple app using Xcode for iOS 8, and used the new "Visual Effects View with Blur and Vibrancy" object in the interface builder. It works great for text but all the images seem to **only work in the simulators**, and none on any hardware.

To illustrate exactly what I mean, here's a comparison.
Screenshot in simulator (intended look):
[image: simulator screenshot]

Screenshot on iPhone (8.3, same as simulator version):
[image: iPhone screenshot]

So the three round elements are: an image, a button with the same image as background, and the same button but without the vibrancy effect ("norm. btn"). It seems like the blur + vibrancy effect is done in Xcode by having two "Visual Effect views" - a top view that implements just blur, and a nested view that also has "vibrancy" checked in the attributes window.

Any idea why this is happening? I really like the looks of the vibrancy in images, but it's not working on my iPhone 5s or my iPad Air 2.

Many thanks!!!

**Update:**
I did some research, and found that I was getting the warning " is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1." Initially I thought that was breaking the vibrancy effect, but upon removing all animations and not getting the warning any more, the images are still invisible. I found out that the warning simply means when the alpha of the VisualEffectView is not yet 1, the vibrancy doesn't begin working (looks grey-ish).

I also found that the images do show (in a "broken" way, i.e. looks black not vibrant as a transition), but they disappear when alpha reaches 1.

Comment: You didn't mention any animations in your question, so what exactly are we talking about here?

Comment: @matt I used zoom and fade (CGAffineTransformMakeScale and alpha) over time (UIView.animateWithDuration).

To clarify, though, I built a new project from scratch with literally nothing but a normal background image, and a blur+vibrancy layer. Images don't show up. No animations or any handwritten code involved, straight from interface builder.

Comment: Very cool. Can you post the demo project? If we have a clear difference between simulator and device, that is material for a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @matt Not sure if this is how you share a repo, but here you go: [link](https://bitbucket.org/HansenLiang/vibrancytestproject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a partial solution: switch your image in the asset catalog to be a template image:

[image]

At least this way you'll see *something* on the device.

**EDIT** Actually, Apple is explicit about this. I quote from the *UIVisualEffectView.h* header:

> UIImageView will need its image to have a rendering mode of UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate to receive the proper effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wouldn't that be the same as putting the images over the vibrancy view?

Comment: Would it? Looks nice on my iPhone, with your Bitbucket demo project. Very colorful. A lot better than not seeing the image at all!

Comment: could you please share a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, this is your bitbucket demo project running on my iPhone 4s after I made the change I described in my answer: http://imgur.com/TAXMT2Y